How to solve for Nash Equilibrium?
Image:

I am currently studying for a college exam next week in Games Theorie. Unfortunately the example questions are very different to the course material and im stuck on this one. I would solve the issue in a) through solving the propaility / payoff functions. but I don't get the delta=1 part. I would be very great full if somebody could help me with that issue.
Question
Consider the game Rock, Paper, Scissors. Both players simultaneously choose one of the three options Rock, Paper or Scissors. A player who plays R will beat another player who has chosen S ("rock crushes scissors") but will lose to one who has played P ("paper covers rock"); a play of P will lose to a play of S (*scissors cut paper"). Assume that the payoffs are the following: when a player wins, the payoff is 1 and when she loses the payoff is -1-. if both players choose the same item and there is a tie, each get 0 points.
a) Let delta= -1. Show that the mixed-strategy Nash-equilibrium of thegameRock,Paper,Scissors is (1/3,1/3,1/3)(1/3,1/3,1/3)
b) 2( points) For which values of delta Scissors, Rock) becomes a pure strategy Nash-equilibrium?

That is very basic stuff.
For $\delta = -1$, it becomes the standard rock-scissor-paper game. To show that both players playing each strategy with probability $1/3$ is a Nash equilibrium, you need to show that if one of the players does that, the other player is indifferent between his three strategies (i.e., the expected payoffs of all three strategies are the same). If that is the case, the other player is willing to randomise, specifically also willing to play the $(1/3,1/3,1/3)$ strategy. As the game is symmetric, nobody has an incentive to deviate then from the equilibrium where they both randomise with those probabilities, and we have a proper mixed strategy Nash equilibrium.
For the second part, we observe that if Player 2 chooses Rock with probability 1, Player 1 only chooses Scissors with probability 1 if the payoff of Scissors is at least as high as the payoff of Paper. This is fulfilled if $\delta \geq 1$. If Player 1 actually does choose Scissors with probability 1, Player 2 has no incentive to deviate from his choice of playing Rock with probability 1, so we have a Nash equilirium in pure strategies.

Ah i See, I might have confused myself. thank you for your clarification
